# Why doesn't this Makefile compile correctly?

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-construction

I've got the following Makefile:

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-c -pedantic -std=c++11 -lglfw -lGL -lGLU -lX11 -lXxf86vm -lXrandr -lpthread -lXi

all: Set GLDrawableGraph Edge Graph Play main

Set: Set.cpp Set.h
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o Set Set.cpp

GLDrawableGraph:  GLDrawableGraph.cpp GLDrawableGraph.h Edge.h Graph.h 
         $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o GLDrawableGraph GLDrawableGraph.cpp

Edge:  Edge.cpp Edge.h
         $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o Edge Edge.cpp

Graph:  Graph.cpp GLDrawableGraph.h Edge.h Graph.h Play.h
         $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o Graph Graph.cpp

Play:  Play.cpp GLDrawableGraph.h Edge.h Graph.h  Play.h
         $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o Play Play.cpp

main:  main.cpp GLDrawableGraph.o Edge.o Graph.o Play.o GLDrawableGraph.h Edge.h Graph.h Play.h Set.o Set.h
         $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o main main.cpp GLDrawableGraph.cpp Edge.cpp Graph.cpp Play.cpp Set.cpp
```

And I get the following output:

```
GLDrawableGraph.cpp:95:10: error: ‘p’ does not name a type
     auto p=nodes.find(nodenumber);
          ^
GLDrawableGraph.cpp:96:8: error: ‘p’ was not declared in this scope
     if(p==nodes.end()) throw std::string("Tried to color nonexistant vertex");
        ^
GLDrawableGraph.cpp:97:5: error: ‘p’ was not declared in this scope
     p->second.color=col;
     ^
GLDrawableGraph.cpp: In member function ‘void DrawableGraph::DrawGraph(GLFWwindow*) const’:
GLDrawableGraph.cpp:140:15: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘e’ with no type [-fpermissive]
     for(auto &e : edges) {
               ^
GLDrawableGraph.cpp:140:19: error: range-based ‘for’ loops are not allowed in C++98 mode
     for(auto &e : edges) {
                   ^
GLDrawableGraph.cpp:141:18: error: request for member ‘first’ in ‘e’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
         int i1=e.first.first;
                  ^
GLDrawableGraph.cpp:142:18: error: request for member ‘first’ in ‘e’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
         int i2=e.first.second;
                  ^
GLDrawableGraph.cpp:151:28: error: request for member ‘second’ in ‘e’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
         RGB rgb=RGBColor(e.second.color);
                            ^
GLDrawableGraph.cpp:158:15: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘p’ with no type [-fpermissive]
     for(auto &p : nodes) {
               ^
GLDrawableGraph.cpp:158:19: error: range-based ‘for’ loops are not allowed in C++98 mode
     for(auto &p : nodes) {
                   ^
GLDrawableGraph.cpp:159:26: error: request for member ‘second’ in ‘p’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
         float xx=float(p.second.x-R.l)/(R.r-R.l)*1.8-0.9;
                          ^
GLDrawableGraph.cpp:160:26: error: request for member ‘second’ in ‘p’, which is of non-class type ‘int’
         float yy=float(p.second.y-R.b)/(R.t-R.b)*1.8-0.9;
```

I tought these errors were from the C++11 differences from the regular C++, but I've already given the -std=c++11 option and it still does not work.

Comment: what version of gcc are you using?

Comment: You want CXXFLAGS, not CFLAGS for g++

Comment: Perhaps showing the code around line 95 of `GLDrawableGraph.cpp` would be a good starting point, at least the function that is in question at that point... What is `p`, and why is `gcc` confused about its type? @stark Generally, that's right, but given the way the `makefile` is written, that is probably not the issue in this case...

Comment: @twalberg, actually using `$(CXXFLAGS)` would have fixed the problem, because it would have been picked up by the implicit rule used to build `GLDrawableGraph.o`

Comment: Do not include `-c` in `CFLAGS` (or `CXXFLAGS`). It means *compile only* and thus prevents linking. Add the `-c` to object file generation rules only.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Yeah, I didn't catch the `-c` in CFLAGS, which renders the explicitly stated rule for the target executable a bit broken... Removing the `-c` from CFLAGS should fix it as well, since the rule to explicitly build the executable from source is there - although still switching to `$(CXX)` and `$(CXXFLAGS)` would be a good idea...

Comment: @twalberg, no, see my comment on Maxim's answer. The `main` target has a `.o` prerequisite and there is no recipe for it, so it uses the built-in rule for compiling a C++ file which uses `$(CXXFLAGS)`, which does not contain `-std=c++11` by default.

Answer (score 2):

Your makefile dependencies are not correct. What happens is that it compiles your project using the built-in rules, hence your flags don't apply and the compiler does not recognize C++11 `auto` keyword. Try compiling with `make -r` to disable the built-in rules and see what happens.

You probably want something like this:

```
CXX := g++
CPPLAGS := -Wall -Wextra
CXXFLAGS := -std=c++11
LDLIBS := -lglfw -lGL -lGLU -lX11 -lXxf86vm -lXrandr -lpthread -lXi

all : main

main : main.o GLDrawableGraph.o Edge.o Graph.o Play.o Set.o 
    ${CXX} -o $@ $^ ${LDLIBS}

%.o : %.cpp # also auto-generates dependencies
    ${CXX} -c -o $@ ${CPPLAGS} ${CXXFLAGS} -MD -MP -MF ${@:.o=.d} $<

-include $(wildcard *.d) # include auto-generated dependencies
```

Comment: To be precise, the `main` target has `GLDrawableGraph.o` as a prerequisite, but there is no recipe to build `GLDrawableGraph.o`, so the built-in rules are used to compile `GLDrawableGraph.cpp`, which uses `$(CXX)` and `$(CXXFLAGS)` not `$(CC)` and `$(CFLAGS)`. The makefile above fixes all those problems.